# How Can I Change Values Chart in docx file using c#

Tags: c#, charts

I am looking for a solution to Change Values  Chart in docx file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be a little more specific?
I would look into the [VSTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/getting-started-programming-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2022) extension. They are COM plugins and can be accessed and can get probably interact with charts inside your document.

Comment: I have a Docx file  that it has 3 Charts.now I wanna change the values chart like categories or Caregoeis 's values  by C# and save File ..Before that I try that by "aspose.Word" But I dont Have Licence file to cover all pages in my File

Comment: i try do that by DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Chartsheet